# How to change Google Map location by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, maps

I'm trying to make a button that changes the location of my map. I've seen many answers, but I can't seem to make those scripts work on my map or on my website. I'm very confuse and I don't understand why they won't work.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="info-map">
    <ul class="loks">
        <li class="active">
            <a id="link1" href="#office" data-toggle="tab">office</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="link2" href="#showroom" data-toggle="tab">showroom</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  #map {
    height: 400px;
  }

  .info-map {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    top: 30px;
    left: 8%;
  }
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
  var map;
function initMap()    { 

var office = {
  info: '<strong>Architectural Art Crete - Office</strong><br>5815 Dewey St, Hollywood, FL 33023, USA',
  lat: 26.0020213,
  long: -80.2058833
};

var showroom = {
  info: '<strong>Showroom</strong><br>1025 W Belmont Ave<br> Chicago, IL 60657',
  lat: 41.939670,
  long: -87.655167
};

var locations = [
    [office.info, office.lat, office.long, 0],
    [showroom.info, showroom.lat, showroom.long, 1],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.0020213, -80.2058833),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
      return function () {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
  })(marker, i));
}
}
```

I found this googleAPI solution that helped me a little but I can't seem to make it work for both locations

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('link2'),
'click', function () {

map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(10.23,123.45));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some problem. Please close the `info:` data properly. you have missed single quote and a comma.

Change

`info: '<strong>Architectural Art Crete - Office</strong><br>\
                5815 Dewey St, Hollywood, FL 33023, USA,`

To

`info: '<strong>Architectural Art Crete - Office</strong><br>5815 Dewey St, Hollywood, FL 33023, USA',`

See the updated code.

```
var map;
function initMap()    { 

    var office = {
      info: '<strong>Architectural Art Crete - Office</strong><br>5815 Dewey St, Hollywood, FL 33023, USA',
      lat: 26.0020213,
      long: -80.2058833
    };

    var showroom = {
      info: '<strong>Showroom</strong><br>1025 W Belmont Ave<br> Chicago, IL 60657',
      lat: 41.939670,
      long: -87.655167
    };

    var locations = [
        [office.info, office.lat, office.long, 0],
        [showroom.info, showroom.lat, showroom.long, 1],
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.0020213, -80.2058833),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

One fix is here:

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('link2'), 'click', function () {
     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(10.23,123.45));
    }
});`

This function was not closed properly a `}` was missing.
Check after update the new code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I fixed it. Still not being able to make the button work though :(

Answer (score 0):

Your latitude and longitude also seem to be an issue. Use the below and ensure that you include these functions inside your initMap function. It would work.

```
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('link2'),
                                             'click', function () {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(showroom.lat, showroom.long));
            });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('link1'),
                                             'click', function () {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(office.lat, office.long));
            });
```